# PHP function to remove occurrences of certain characters from a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I need a PHP function that will take a string as input, and return the string minus all occurrences of these characters:
! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]

Is there something already built for this purpose or can it be accomplished with regex? I'd rather not do 20 different str_replace function calls on this string. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you need whitelisting more than blacklisting. What *do* you want to allow?

Comment: @chelmertz, really I just need to remove those exact characters from a string. Everything else is fair game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use str_replace with arrays:

```
// $arrayOfCharsToReplace = array('!','*', ...etc

$clean = str_replace(
    $arrayOfCharsToReplace, 
    array_fill(0, count($arrayOfCharsToReplace), ''), // array of empty strings
    $unclean
);
```

You can also use `strtr` like so:

```
// $arrayOfReplacements = array('!' => '', '*' => '', ...etc

$clean = strtr($unclean, $arrayOfReplacements);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$quoted = preg_quote('!*\'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]','/');
$sanitized = preg_replace('/['.$quoted.']/', '', $string);
```

If in general, you'd like punctuation replaced, use a regex class instead (it's shorter and readable):

```
$sanitized = preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtr` (this is preferred) or `preg_replace` (this is slower).